# compare a new csv data with master data and remove duplicates from the new csv and get cleaned csv data from the file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a master file with two columns that contain data from all the old records. whenever I get a new data file with two columns, I want to compare it with the master file and remove the duplicate values from the new file and get cleaned data from the new data without changing anything in the master file.

```
np.setdiff1d(new_file, master_file)
```

I have tried the above code but it's not giving the desired results

Comment: Cleaned in what sense?

Comment: Can you provide an example that includes the data being input to the process i.e. both master and the new file and an example of what you expect to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really quick fix solution, it's not very robust to changes in the files and it is have some iterations. But if it's relative small files and a one-off, this works.

```
test_master = pd.read_csv('data/test_master.csv')
test_new = pd.read_csv('data/test_new.csv')

drop_these = []

for i,d in enumerate(zip(test_new.iloc[:,0], test_new.iloc[:,1])):
    if d in zip(test_master.iloc[:,0], test_master.iloc[:,1]):
        drop_these.append(i)
        
test_new.drop(drop_these, inplace=True)
```

Also if you don't want to use pandas, not the most optimal solution:

```
import csv

master_file = []
with open("data/test_master.csv", "r") as f:
    writer = csv.reader(f)
    for row in writer:
        master_file.append(row)

new_file = []
with open("data/test_new.csv", "r") as f:
    writer = csv.reader(f)
    for row in writer:
        if row not in master_file:
            new_file.append(row)
```